# React перенаправить ref наоборот

Tags: reactjs, ref

Есть компонент в котором создается несколько вложенных DOM узлов, к одному из которых прикреплен ref (прикреплен он не просто так и он должен остаться):

```
const Some = ({ ...props }) => {
  const barRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (barRef.current) {
      console.log(barRef.current);
    }
  }, [barRef]);

  return (
    <div className="foo" {...props}>
      <div className="bar" ref={barRef}>
        &npsp;
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Задача в том, чтобы когда мы прикрепляем ref к компоненту Some, отдавался именно barRef:

```
const Main = () => {
  const someRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (someRef.current) {
      console.log(someRef.current); // Тут должен быть barRef
    }
  }, [someRef]);

  return(<Some ref={someRef}/>);
};
```

Как мне это сделать без устаревшего callback refs (https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через [перенаправление рефов](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

```
const Some = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div className="foo" {...props}>
      <div className="bar" ref={ref}>
        &npsp;
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: А каким образом я тогда смогу взаимодействовать с ref внутри компонента Some? Мне же его нужно не просто прокинуть наружу, а взаимодействовать с ним как в Some, так и в Main

Comment: @posix в Some можешь обращаться к нему через ref

Comment: спасибо, действительно работает. А верным ли путем будет сделать в начале компонента: if (!ref) ref = React.createRef(); на случай если ref не задан? Или это делается как-то по другому?

Comment: @posix Вообще, лучше все манипуляции с рефом в таком примере делать в родительском компоненте Main, т.к компонент Some является лишь "глупым" потребителем "пропа" реф.